# Referencing previous frames values Python Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have a really simple piece of code.  What I would like to do as the program loops at 60 fps is I want to reference the previous mouse click state.  i.e. I have 'one' as the variable for mouse click state, 0 for not clicked and 1 for clicked.  What I want to happen is If the mouse is currently clicked i.e. one = 1 & the previous value of one was 0 i.e. unclicked then save the value of mx and my which are the mouse co-ordinates.  Please see the code below:

```
PDimageFull = pygame.image.load('F:\Project files\coils\PDsinwaveResize.jpg')
PDresX = 300
PDresY = 720

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((Display_Width,Display_Height))


pygame.display.set_caption('PD diagnostic tool')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def PDimage(x, y):
    gameDisplay.blit(PDimageFull, (x, y))

# Defining our main programing loop

def mainProgram_loop():
    dx1 = (Display_Width-PDresX)
    dy1 = (Display_Height-PDresY)



    gameExit = False

# Event handling
    while not gameExit:
        mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        one, two, three = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True

            # This expression controls the movement of the overall PD graph
            # The section in the IF statement defines the boundary by which you can move the object
            if one == 1 and mx > dx1 and mx < dx1 + PDresX and my > dy1 and my < dy1+PDresY:

                dx1 = dx1 + (mx - PDresX)
                dy1 = dy1 + (my - PDresY)

        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        PDimage(dx1, dy1)
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)


mainProgram_loop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use another variable:

```
prev_one = one
one, two, three = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

if prev_one == 0 and one == 1:
    print 'mouse was clicked this frame'
```

Be aware that you will have to initialise `one` with a default value at the start of your script.